# Error when trying to create postgis extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have looked at all the answers on this topic, but none of them solved the issue that I have. I would really appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue.

version: `psql (9.1.4, server 9.2.4)` OS: Mac OS X (Mavericks)

Method 1:
When trying to create an extension on my database (mydb), using the below commands:

```
$ sudo su postgres
$ psql mydb
> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I get

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/local/share/postgresql92/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

When I dig deeper I found that `postgis.control` is actually located in `/opt/opengeo/pgsql/9.1/share/postgresql/extension`

It occurs to me that I have both postgresql 9.1 and 9.2 on my machine.

Method 2:
I have also tried to create an extension by following the below steps:

```
$ su - postgres 
$ cd /opt/opengeo/pgsql/9.1/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.0
$ psql -d mydb -f postgis.sql
```

It comes with a list of errors:

`psql:postgis.sql:6056: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK`

**Please suggest where am I going wrong ?**

Comment: You haven't said whether it's the 9.1 or 9.2 installation you want to install postgis in and whether the 9.2 version has the postgis extension available.

Comment: 9.2 version doesn't have a postgis extension available, therefore I would want to install postgis in ver 9.1

Comment: Your initial error mentioned 9.2 though - are you sure you're connecting to the right version?